# jQuery Running Several Dynamically Created Timers

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

### What I Am Trying To Achieve

My site has multiple crons to fetch external data for site members game information. This page I am creating shows the last fetched data scope, time and what I am trying to implement, a countdown timer until the next fetch.

1. Page Load
2. Timers Start
3. Timer Ends
4. Timer Text: Fetching Data...
5. Timer restarts

---

### Problems I Am Having

Working with one timer has been fairly easy, however this page needs several dozen and thus dynamic timer names to stop / start and whatnot. This is a somewhat basic version to answer this question upon having several timers running this way, hence the `30`, `60`, `90` and `120` intervals.

---

### My jQuery Timer *- Working*

[>> View On CodePen <<](https://codepen.io/MrTIMarshall2512/pen/eRXJxL?editors=1010)

```
var timer = 20;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    timer--;

    var H  = Math.floor((timer % (60 * 60 * 24)) / (60 * 60));
    var HH = (H < 9 ? "0" : "") + H;
    var M  = Math.floor((timer % (60 * 60)) / 60);
    var MM = (M < 9 ? "0" : "") + M;
    var S  = Math.floor(timer % 60);
    var SS = (S < 9 ? "0" : "") + S;

    $('.timer').text(HH + ":" + MM + ":" + SS);
    if (timer === 0) clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```

---

### Multiple Timer Attempt

[>> View on CodePen <<](https://codepen.io/MrTIMarshall2512/pen/zzbLwK?editors=1010)

```
$('.timer').each(function(){
    var timer_interval = $(this).data("interval");
    var timer_name = $(this).data("timer-name");
    startTimer(timer_name, timer_interval);
});
function startTimer(name, interval) {
    var name = setInterval(function() {
        timer--;
        var H  = Math.floor((interval % (60 * 60 * 24)) / (60 * 60));
        var HH = (H < 9 ? "0" : "") + H;
        var M  = Math.floor((interval % (60 * 60)) / 60);
        var MM = (M < 9 ? "0" : "") + M;
        var S  = Math.floor(interval % 60);
        var SS = (S < 9 ? "0" : "") + S;

        $('.timer').text(HH + ":" + MM + ":" + SS);
        if (timer === 0) {
          $('.timer').text("Updating");
          clearInterval(name);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

---

### Questions

1. How can I run several timers with dynamically created names?
2. Upon a timer reaching 0, how can I check which timer has stopped to then pass back through the loop to restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.queue()` to provide a `queueName` to one or more functions to call in sequence, or not in sequence; `.promise()`, `.then()` to provide reschedule the function to be called again when all of the functions in `queueName` array have been called.

```js
function startTimer(queueName, interval, el, next) {
  var timer = interval;
  $(el).data(queueName, setInterval(function() {
    timer--;
    var H = Math.floor((timer % (60 * 60 * 24)) / (60 * 60));
    var HH = (H < 9 ? "0" : "") + H;
    var M = Math.floor((timer % (60 * 60)) / 60);
    var MM = (M < 9 ? "0" : "") + M;
    var S = Math.floor(timer % 60);
    var SS = (S < 9 ? "0" : "") + S;

    $(el).text(HH + ":" + MM + ":" + SS);
    if (timer === 0) {
      $(el).text("Updating");
      clearInterval($(el).data(queueName));
      next();
    }
  }, 1000));
}

function scheduleTimer(elem) {
  return $.when.apply($,
    $.map(elem ? elem : $(".timer"), function(el, index) {
      var timer_interval = $(el).data("interval");
      var timer_name = $(el).data("timer-name");
      return $(el).queue(timer_name, function(next) {
          startTimer(timer_name, timer_interval, el, next)
        }).dequeue(timer_name).promise(timer_name)
        .then(function(el) {
          var timer_name = el.data("timer-name")
          return el.delay(2000, timer_name)
            .queue(timer_name, function(next) {
              scheduleTimer(el)
            }).dequeue(timer_name).promise(timer_name)
        })
    }))
}

scheduleTimer();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div data-interval="30" data-timer-name="Timer1" class="timer">00:00:00</div>
<div data-interval="60" data-timer-name="Timer2" class="timer">00:00:00</div>
<div data-interval="90" data-timer-name="Timer3" class="timer">00:00:00</div>
<div data-interval="120" data-timer-name="Timer4" class="timer">00:00:00</div>
```

Comment: Hiya guest271314, running your code above, after said time, they do change to "Updating" however they don't dynamically countdown or restart?

Comment: @TimMarshall You can create a function which returns `$.when()` call, the function again at `.then()` chained to function call

Comment: @TimMarshall See updated post. Substituted `timer` for `interval` within `startTimer` function; included a function which returns `$.when()` with `.then()` chained where same function is called when all jQuery promises have fulfilled.

Comment: This is a little out of my scope. not done something like this before. Pretty much what I was looking for, however each timer should display "Updating" for a couple of seconds and then restart, not when all timers have completed. Thank you :)

Comment: @TimMarshall You can use `.delay()` with `.queue()` and `.promise()` again within `.then()` chained to `$.when()`. See updated post

Comment: Haha! That sounds really complicated and alien to me right now however I'm sure I'll pick it up with a bit of playing around :)

Answer (score 1):

I think `Timer` was undefined in the `startTimer` function and needed to be renamed. Let me know if this is the functionality you're looking for. Judging by how its currently working on my end, you will need an Id for each timer. I will update my answer when possible if still needed.

```
$('.timer').each(function(){
    var timer_interval = $(this).data("interval");
    var timer_name = $(this).data("timer-name");
    startTimer(timer_name, timer_interval);
});
function startTimer(name, interval) {
    var name = setInterval(function() {
        interval--;
        var H  = Math.floor((interval % (60 * 60 * 24)) / (60 * 60));
        var HH = (H < 9 ? "0" : "") + H;
        var M  = Math.floor((interval % (60 * 60)) / 60);
        var MM = (M < 9 ? "0" : "") + M;
        var S  = Math.floor(interval % 60);
        var SS = (S < 9 ? "0" : "") + S;

        $('.timer').text(HH + ":" + MM + ":" + SS);
        if (interval === 0) {
          $('.timer').text("Updating");
          clearInterval(name);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Hiya lloyd, this has got the timers to work, however all are displaying the same countdown. Just trying to figure this out now, I see I need to pass `$(this)` to update the correct timer.[Updated Demo](https://codepen.io/MrTIMarshall2512/pen/KqEBGd?editors=1010)